# bootstrap datepicker style - yellow ribbon

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker

I would like to know why there are yellow ribbon on the disabled dates??

Please take a look at the captured picture.

Thanks for your help in advance.

[Datepicker yellow ribbon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doiqO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It was another css file that had same selector.

I troubleshoot by inspecting the elements on the calendar.